# Pandas: Series and DataFrames handling of datetime objects

Tags: pandas, datetime

Pandas behaves in an unusual way when interacting with datetime information when the data type is a Series vs when it is not. Specifically, either `.dt` is required (if it's a Series) or `.dt` will throw an error (if it's not a Series.) I've spent the better part of an hour tracking the behavior down.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'dates':['2019-03-01','2019-03-02'],'event':[0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
```

Pandas Series:

```py
df['dates'][0:1].dt.year
>>> 
0    2019
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```

```py
df['dates'][0:1].year
>>>
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'
```

Not Pandas Series:

```py
df['dates'][0].year
>>>
2019
```

```py
df['dates'][0].dt.year
>>>
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

Does anyone know *why* Pandas behaves this way? Is this a "feature not a bug" like it's actually useful in setting?

Comment: `.dt` is a property on a Series object. When it's not a Series, it doesn't have that property. What's unusual about that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is consistent with python. A *collection* of datetimes is fundamentally different than a single datetime.

We can see this simply with `list` vs `datetime` object:

```
from datetime import datetime

a = datetime.now()
print(a.year) 
# 2021

list_of_datetimes = [datetime.now(), datetime.now()]
print(list_of_datetimes.year)
# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'year'
```

Naturally a list does not have a year attribute, because in python we cannot guarantee the list contains only datetimes.

We would have to apply some function to each element in the list to access the `year`, for example:

```
from datetime import datetime

list_of_datetimes = [datetime.now(), datetime.now()]

print(*map(lambda d: d.year, list_of_datetimes))
# 2021 2021
```

This concept of "applying an operation over a collection of datetimes" is fundamentally what the `dt` accessor does. By extension, this accessor is unnecessary when affecting a single element as it is when working with only a single datetime.

---

In `pandas` we can only use the `dt` accessor with DateTime Series.

There are a lot of guarantees needed to be made in order to apply the year to all elements in the Series:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'dates': ['2019-03-01', '2019-03-02'], 'event': [0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
print(df['dates'].dt.year)
```

```
0    2019
1    2019
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```

Again, however, since a column of object type *could* contain both datetimes and non-datetimes we may need to access the individual elements. Like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'dates': ['2019-03-01', 87], 'event': [0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
#         dates  event
# 0  2019-03-01      0
# 1          87      1

# Convert only 1 value to datetime
df.loc[0, 'dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[0, 'dates'])
print(df.loc[0, 'dates'].year)
# 2019
print(df.loc[1, 'dates'].year)
# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'year'
```